# Angular/Primeng - Implement p-autocomplete dropdown with no button

Tags: html, angular, autocomplete, dropdown, primeng

I have a "p-autocomplete" element with multiple entries and dropdown enabled, and am wondering if I can do so without displaying the button, but instead show the dropdown menu when users click on the autocomplete field.

Is this possible with this type of object?

I am using Primeng version 4.3.0, if it makes a difference.

**HTML:**

```
<p-autoComplete id="input-country" [multiple]="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountries" [dropdown]="true"
          [suggestions]="filteredCountries" (completeMethod)="filterCountryMultipe($event)">
                 <ng-template let-selectedCountries pTemplate="item">
                 ....
          </ng-template>
 </p-autoComplete>
```

===================
UPDATE=====================
Thank you to olivier-depriester for your answer below. In addition to the onFocus method, I also removed the dropdown property and handled everything with the autocomplete, simply amending the filter method to accept an empty query.

Current HTML:

```
<p-autoComplete id="input-country" [multiple]="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountries" (onFocus)="onFocus()"
                    [suggestions]="filteredCountries" (completeMethod)="filterCountryMultiple($event)" >
                <ng-template let-selectedCountries pTemplate="item">
                    ....
                </ng-template>
            </p-autoComplete>
```

Current Typescript:

```
onFocus(){
    this.filterCountryMultiple({query:''});
    this.autoComplete.show();
}

filterCountryMultiple(event) {
    let query = event.query;
    this.filteredCountriesMultiple = this.filterCountry(query);
}

filterCountry(query):any[] {
....
    for(let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        let country = countries[i];
        if(...query is empty...){
            filtered.push(country.code);
        }
        else if(...match found...) {
            filtered.push(country.code);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With primeng 6.5 to 7.0, I used the `show` function, bound on the `focus` event.

On typescript side :

```js
export class MyComponent {
    @ViewChild(AutoComplete) private autoComplete: AutoComplete;

    onFocus() {
        this.autoComplete.show();
    }
}
```

And on HTML side :

```html
<p-autoComplete id="input-country" [multiple]="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountries" [dropdown]="true"
    [suggestions]="filteredCountries"
    (completeMethod)="filterCountry($event)"
    (onFocus)="onFocus($event)">
         <ng-template let-selectedCountries pTemplate="item">
             <div class="ui-helper-clearfix" style="border-bottom:1px solid #D5D5D5">
                   .......
         </ng-template>
</p-autoComplete>
```

But in primeng current version (v8), this method is no more documented. So I don't know if it still exists